# Create relative web path from file path

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim wdgtUrl = Path.Combine(Root, "widgets").Replace("\", "/")
Dim rootDir As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(wdgtUrl)
sb.Append(String.Format("<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""{0}""></script>", Root.TrimStart({"~"c}) + "/custom.js"))
If System.IO.Directory.Exists(rootDir) AndAlso System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootDir, "*.js", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length > 0 Then
  For Each Path As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootDir, "*.js", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    sb.Append(String.Format("<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""/{0}""></script>", Path.Replace(Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"), [String].Empty).Replace("\", "/")))
  Next
End If
```

I am using the following code to search a directory, and create a script tag for each JavaScript file within the directory. This works fine locally, but on a  production site the scripts return a 404 response, as the link starts with:

/E:/WEB/Major/

I would have expected

`Path.Replace(Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"), [String].Empty)`

to replace this, but it hasn't in this instance. On the production box the folder is a virtual directory, whereas locally it ins't. I created a virtual directory locally to test and get the same issue.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: If this is called on each page, you should think of using an other strategy. Going on the HD like this will kill performance. A good strategy is to combine (and compress) all js file in a compile script and add this file only to your site.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET 4.5 then you might be interested in [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).

Comment: Thanks guys, nearly all scripts are bundled and minified. These are the exception and its some legacy stuff. Good point about performance @the_lotus, Ill think of something.

Comment: You could call [System.IO.Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the filename only and hardcode the relative path (ex: src=""somepath/{0}").

Comment: Thanks @the_lotus, I manually manipulated the string to remove the parts that were not needed

Comment: Also, if these script are "legacy stuff". I'm pretty sure you could just hardcode them inside a list of a config file instead of looking on the harddrive.